# Fusion Chart (bar2d) is not able to scroll in React Native

Tags: react-native, graph, charts, scrollview, fusioncharts

I have implemented fusion chart (bar2d) type in my react native application. Its working fine, If the data is around 10-12 lines (graph lines) showing fine, But, If its 30 lines, Its getting shrink and adjusting the given height only.

Its not even enabling the scrollview (like flatlist), And the UI looks very inconsistent, Even, I tried to add the scrollview to Fusion Chart, But, Its not working. Because, The view is not getting expand, How to enable scroll, or according to data how to increase the view height.

> Even, I contacted them regarding this issue, They told bar charts
>   don't have scrollview, Scroll contains only Vertical/Column charts.
>   But, My requirement is bar chart.

My output is  following screenshot,
[image]

Actual, Which I am looking for is following screenshot.

[image]

And My code is

```
<View style={styles.container} />
<FusionCharts
  type={type}
  width={width}
  height={height} // given 95%
  dataFormat={dataFormat}
  dataSource={dataSource} //dynamic json data which contains around 30 indexes
  libraryPath={fusionChartPath}
/>
```

> How can I achieve this?

Comment: FusioCharts does not have a scroll feature in the horizontal bar type charts instead use a scrollcolumn2d chart that can fits your requirements - http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/nAa33/

Comment: But, my requirement is bar chart, not vertical charts.

Comment: drop a mail to support@fusioncharts.com, they can give you the best solution here

Comment: I already contacted them, They told as of now, They are not providing scrollview for bar charts.

Comment: you have shared on their GitHub page try sending a mail to them to the above email id

Comment: Sure, Thank you